# How to allow CORS in Yii2?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, cors, localhost

I have a JavaScript frontend that ask for a plain text to my PHP backend.

It almost works excepts because I have a CORS problem. How can allow CORS in my PHP code?

**My frontend (JavaScript and jQuery):**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("Oh, no. CORS error again.");
});
```

**My backend (PHP and Yii2):**

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://m2m.exemys.com/...'); // This URL is a bit larger with more parameters.
var_dump($result); // Plain text. Just some characters.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-Origin Request Headers(CORS) with PHP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii2 supports CORS handling, as written on the [official documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-cors).

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::class,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Alternatively, you could try adding the following headers on your PHP backend:

```php
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
```

If doesn't work, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/11591212

Answer (score 1):

Check this. Yii2 comes with cors filter out of the box. Read Documentattion to understand the usage  : https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-cors